# Use timer to change image

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

in my master page header i would like to display multiple images and have them change every 2 seconds or so. how would i go about implementing something like this?

Im using Microsoft visual studio 2010 and using vb.net

although i have just found this code, is there any way i get this to work in event handler of the timer. i understand it is not VB.net but can i use any imports?

```
 protected void gettickvalue(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

{

Random RandomNumber = new Random();

int n = RandomNumber.Next(1, 9);

imgBanner.ImageUrl = System.String.Concat("images/banner_", n.ToString(), ".gif");

Comment: Have you tired searching [similar](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=k4A9U-uCFcjR8gfEloCYCA#q=how%20to%20change%20image%20periodically%20in%20asp.net)??

Comment: just seen this @huMptyduMpty thanks, do you know if there is any way i can use the above code on a vb page or advise of how to implement it?

Comment: I suggest to use client side solution!! Try one of the jquery image gallery... there are hundreds of examples online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that ASP runs server side, you probably don't want a timer running there.  Your better solution is a JavaScript (client side) timer:

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
```